# Turn off iPhone screen sharing after Apple Support call? (Revoke permissions granted)

Tags: iphone, permission, sharing

I had a call with Apple Tech Support and they asked to share my iPhone (11, latest iOS) screen.  I granted them permission (clicking swiftly through a number of screens that popped up) and they moved a cursor around on the screen and told me where to click.

Just to be on the safe side, how can I make sure that I've ended all sharing permissions, now that the call has ended?  I looked in settings, but I don't see how to "undo" what I did (or if it's possible), that is, revoke any permissions granted.

I'm assuming it just automatically ends when the call ends, but since it's fairly invasive to be screen sharing, I just wanted to double-check within the iPhone settings themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When screen sharing is active, you'll see it in the status bar. I believe it's purple or red, but may be wrong.

After the call ends the status bar coloring should go away. If this is the case, then you're all set. No further action is needed. Permission needs to be granted to restart the share.

If you would like to be absolutely sure, then you could restart the device.